# Why is my Unauthorzied request not getting redirected to AccessDenied URL in ASP.Net MVC Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-middleware

I have my AccountAdmin Controller where I manage Users in Identity.

So I have the Authorize Attribute like this at the top of the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AccountAdminController : Controller
```

The whole system is working great.  If I log in as a user with the Admin role I can get to the page.  And if I log in as a user without the Admin role I cannot get to the page.  But my problem is that instead of being redirected to the "Account/AccessDenied" Page, I just get the "/AccountAdmin/Index" URL where I am denied the content and it just gives me the "Status Code: 403; Forbidden" message from:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

in my startup.

In StartUp.ConfigureServices I have:

```
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;

            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

In StartupConfigure I have:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

I know I haven't posted a lot of code here but it's all pretty straight forward stuff.
The caveaot is I am using Windows Authentication.  I show the user login like DomainName\UserName in the UpperRight corner.
And then I made kind of an Impersonation Sign in Page where we can Sign in with TestRole1, TestRole2, etc.

The AccountController looks like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
    private UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    public AccountController(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, 
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(_userManager.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, bool persistant)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName), persistant);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

It's all working pretty well as far as Authentication and Authorization goes.
Accept I found that until I click my SignIn my real windows account won't match up with the roles I assigned to myself.  It has to go through the SignInManager at:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, bool persistant)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName), persistant);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

How can I get this AccessDenied redirect working?

---

Update 1:

I tried to make a filter like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Access/Denied");
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I try to replace the standard Authorize Attribute with this:

```
[MyAuthorizationFilter(Roles = "Admin")]
```

it doesn't know what "Roles" is.
It says: "The type or namespace Roles could not be found. Are you missing an assembly or namespace?"

Comment: I would be curious to know it `options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";` would work with Windows Auth. I doubt it, but...shrug.

Comment: Gave it a shot. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well it took me a while to work out how I want to do this.  But here it is.
I didn't want this to go through error handling because it is not an unhandled error.
It is handled with app.UseStatusCodePages(); in StartUp.Configure.

So on a line below that in StartUp.Configure I add:

```
// 400 - 599
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/Account/Status/{0}");
```

This is a place I can redirect to handle what I want to do with specific statuses but leave a default for what I don't specify.

The "Account/Status" action in the Account controller looks like this.

```
    public IActionResult Status()
    {
        string statusCode = HttpContext.Request.Path;
        statusCode = statusCode.Substring(statusCode.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
        return View(ViewBag);
    }
```

and the view looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-header">
            <h3>StatusCode: 
                @switch ((string)ViewBag.StatusCode)
                {
                    case "403":
                        @:Access Denied
                        <div style="margin-top:5px"><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" class="btn btn-primary">Login as a different user</a></div>
                    break;
                default:
                        @ViewBag.StatusCode
                        break;
                }
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just wanted this to stay out of the way of my error handling when I get to plugging that in.  That is something different.

There must be a simple setting somewhere. But none of these solutions I see like AuthenticatonChallenge = true and so forth are working for me.
I think this is pretty tidy for now.